# If C-14 has a half-life of $5750$ years and an artifact has lost $22.3\%$ of its original C-14, how old is the artifact?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Carbon dating: The radioactive element carbon-14 has a half-life of 5750 years. The percentage of Carbon-14 present in the remains of organic matter can be used to date the age of organic matter. Archaeologists discovered that the linen wrapping from one end of the Dead Sea Scrolls had lost 22.3% of its Carbon-14 at the time it was found. How old was the linen wrapping?

I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add some details?  Can you explain what a "half-life" is?  Can you describe the mathematical model which gives the quantity of C-14 in a sample at some specified time if the sample started with 100 g of C-14?

Answer (score 2):

I will give you the setup of the problem and leave the algebra to you.

It's a standard $Pe^{rt}$ problem. We know at $t = 0$, we have $100\%$ of the Carbon, right? So $f(0) = 1 = Pe^{0r} = P$.

So then we know at $t = 5750$, there is $50\%$ of the carbon remaining. So $f(5750) = e^{5750 * r} = \frac{1}{2}$. That gives you enough information to solve for $r$.

Now you set up $f(t) = 0.223 = e^{rt}$. Plug in your result for $r$ from the previous equation and solve for $t$.